# Direct data transfer from memory mapped file file to network channel in Rust

Tags: linux, asynchronous, rust

I am porting a Java application whose main attribute is to be able to move data between memory mapped files and the network without copy and have been trying to figure out how to achieve the same in Rust.

Here's a simple example of what I want to achieve in rust, written in Java:

```java
import ...

public final class Service {

    static final SocketAddress LOCAL = new InetSocketAddress(9000);
    static final Path FILE = Paths.get("/tmp/file.txt");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Files.writeString(FILE, "Hello, World!\n", CREATE, WRITE);
        try (FileChannel file = FileChannel.open(FILE, READ)) {
            MappedByteBuffer buffer = file.map(READ_ONLY, 0, file.size());

            try (ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open()) {
                server.bind(LOCAL);

                System.out.printf("waiting for a connection on %s\n", LOCAL);
                try (SocketChannel connection = server.accept()) {

                    // write the memory mapped file buffer directly to the network socket
                    int bytes = connection.write(buffer);

                    SocketAddress client = connection.getRemoteAddress();
                    System.out.printf("written %d bytes to %s\n", bytes, client);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a collection of large memory mapped file bigger than the RAM (i.e 100GB) and and array of entries within those files with file, byte offset position and the size of each entry. I would like to be able to receive a network request for a specific set of entries and write them to the network socket directly from the memory mapped buffer without the need for an intermediate temporary buffer, letting the OS handle all the memory swapping and paging required.

I have been looking into the `std::fs` and `std::net` crates but it looks like these are equivalent to `java.io` and I am looking for something more like `java.nio`.

The platform is Archlinux on my development machine and Debian on production. I do have a preference for async, but synchronous could be a good place to start, subject to further optimisation in the future.

Comment: Your Java code would benefit from [transferTo/transferFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo-long-long-java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel-).

Comment: Because "Many operating systems can transfer bytes directly from the filesystem cache to the target channel without actually copying them."

Comment: Sounds like you want the [`memmap2` crate](https://crates.io/crates/memmap2/)

Comment: What platform are you on? What framework are you using for the Rust code?

Comment: On Linux, uou can send a file to the network without in-memory copies using `std::io::copy()`, which will internally use the `sendfile()` system call. This is a synchronous call, though, so it will block until the copy is complete. There are alternatives for different platforms and async frameworks, but we can only help if you tell us your requirements.

Comment: tbh, requirements are pretty flexible. I would prefer to use rust standard library, stable (1.72.1 atm), but that is more of a preference than a requirement. There is no need for cross platform or windows/mac support, it will only ever run on linux servers, debian 12 or newer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I guess `std::io::copy()` is all you need in that case. You can use a thread pool to serve multiple concurrent requests.